# Could Fearless Destiny or Tempting Fate affect the Leadership feat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, feats

I'm currently playing a luck-based character in a mixed DnD 3.5/PF setting. I'm thinking of investing in the leadership feat, but I'm worried about a few abilities I have. My character has three different abilities that allow for him to avoid death: Fearless Destiny, Tempting Fate, and Fate's Favored (a class capstone, not the PF trait).

Each of these abilities ensure that if I were to die, instead I am placed at -9 and stabilized. This allows me to help my party in very dangerous situations and still survive catastrophic failure (in most cases).

How would this affect leadership? Could my "death" make cohorts consider me a failure?

**Sources:**
Fearless Destiny - *Races of Destiny* p. 152
Tempting Fate - *Complete Scoundrel* p. 80
[Fate's Favored custom prestige class](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s74/sh/cd6aa6fa-16db-42ec-8fa8-0d0a4dffcf56/f2d084c376dcdf1d87c68e01d6af0fb2)

Comment: So you have a character built around making heroic sacrifices and you think it's going to have a *negative* impact on your reputation with your followers?

Comment: Heroism is subjective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Merely having the features: no, not directly

Unless the feature explicitly says it affects your Leadership score, simply having it is not going to affect your Leadership score.

## If you get a reputation for risky behavior, that might

If these class features affect your decisions, and you take greater risks, and these risks get people killed, *and* you get a reputation for it, that definitely affects your ability to attract a cohort or followers, as “Caused the death of a cohort” is a stated reason for a −2 penalty on your Leadership score for attracting a cohort, and “Caused the death of other followers” is a stated reason to get a −1 penalty on your Leadership score for the purpose of attracting followers.

Beyond that, having a reputation as being aloof or failing, both of which may be true if you callously take risks that you are protected from but those around you are not, and you take risks that result in failure, can each apply a −1 modifier to your overall Leadership score, that is, for all purposes that it gets used for.

So all told, if you’re getting people killed (whether because of this class feature or not), you could be looking at anywhere from −1 to −4 on your Leadership score.

Comment: I really appreciate the clarification. Thanks!